# Simple CSS query: linking... and request for tutorial

Tags: html, css

I am not good with CSS but have downloaded a template off the net and need to work with that.

I am sure this is a pretty simple thing to do, basically in my html file I have this code:

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
```

and in the CSS file I have this code:

```
#topbar {
    height: 104px;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

My question;

1. how do I make the image/logo into a link (without a border of course) so that people can click it and come back to the homepage?
2. please recommend a good tutorial to make "table-less" based layouts for html pages.
   I am kind of old school and only know how to make a layout with a table, I think i need to upgrade my skills :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could make the logo into a link like this:

HTML:

```
 <div id="topbar"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#topbar a {
color: #ffffff;
border: 0;
}
```

**Note:** Background images can't be formatted as links.

Comment: Thanks guys! Voted everyone and picked the answer that I used. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be clickable, you should put the image into the HTML like this:

```
<a href="somewhere.html" id="topbar"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
```

and use

```
#topbar {
    display:block;
    height: 104px;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    border:0;
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to resort to an empty anchor element and/or Javascript, which I'd consider bad practice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

1) Background images can't be made into links. What you could do is make the DIV a link instead:

```
<a id="topbar"></a>`

#topbar {
    height: 104px;
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    display: block;
    border: none;
}
```

2) Google 'css layout' and begin reading. There's hundreds of thousands of tutorials out there. If you are completely lost, I'd start with a good book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Bulletproof-Web-Design-flexibility-protecting/dp/0321509021/ref=pd_sim_b8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)

[http://www.amazon.com/Introducing-HTML5-Voices-That-Matter/dp/0321687299/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318775902&sr=1-7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321687299)

Comment: Links aren't exactly useful you can't tell where they go (and background images don't count, they are backgrounds not content).

Comment: Don't count? Huh? That's what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want your logo to be a background image.  The reason is that background images are not shown when you print.  More than likely, you will want your logo visible on a printed copy.